# Can not run C++ in eclipse mars

Tags: c++, eclipse

I tried to run C++ in Eclipse Mars but it failed. It is showing "Launch failed. Binary not found" .It is also showing another fatal error "sdkddkver.h: No such file or directory". I pasted a snapshot so that you can see these. I have installed MinGw and added the "C:/MinGW/bin" to windows path. The MinGW packages which are added, can be seen in the left on the snapshot. Appreciate any help. I have seen, lot of similar posts, but nothing helped.

[image]

I further explored the process mentioned by ali. I clicked Project -> Build Project.  And I got following error message, which came before also. I fear this may due to this missing file "sdkddkver.h". Related to this missing file "sdkddkver.h" I saw lot of earlier posts also, but not pertaining to this specific problem. Does anybody know about this file? How to get this and will that solve the problem or not.

[image]

Comment: Could you show the compiler command that was issued when you try to run please? It's shown in one of the docked console windows.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ   - I am totally new in this. Would you elaborate where can I find the docked console, you mentioned.

Comment: The fatal error means the compiler could not build a binary. End result, no binary to run. Fix the problems with the code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You must build an object file before you can compile it. So if you don't “BUILD” your file, then it will not be able to link and load that object file, and hence it does not have the required binary numbers to execute.

So basically right click on the Project -> Build Project -> Run As Local C/C++ Application should do the trick

Comment: Doesn't the IDE build automatically by default? Mine does IIRC.

Comment: Eclipse does by default on run or debug. You can turn autobuild off if you want on the  run configuration page.

Comment: Since when are object files compiled?  I thought they were linked into an executable.